# Default parameter value for 'postData' must be a compile-time constant

Tags: c#, .net

I want to login to my MyBB forum with my console application, but I get an error with my code

> Default parameter value for 'postData' must be compile-time constant

I can fix it rather easy if I set my Username and Password to be a const string, but than I can't use Console.ReadLine(); so I would have to hard code the username and password which I don't think is such a good idea.

This is my code:

```
        public  string Username = Console.ReadLine();
    public  string Password = Console.ReadLine();
    public const string ForumUrl = "forum.smurfbot.net";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }

    public string MakePostRequest(string url = "www.website.com/usercp.php", string postData = "username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&remember=yes&submit=Login&action=do_login&url=" + ForumUrl + "member.php?action=login")
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string sReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Dispose();

        return sReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why set a default value for it in the first place? This is not how functions work!

Use separate arguments and perform the string concatenation inside your function.

```
public string MakePostRequest(string url, string Username, string Password, string ForumUrl)
{
    string postData = "username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&remember=yes&submit=Login&action=do_login&url=" + ForumUrl + "member.php?action=login"
    ...
}
```

---

For a method with a name as generic as "MakePostRequest" having a default URL or default POST data sounds very strange.

To be honest, I'd expect it to accept just a URL and a mapping for the POST data and then it's up to the caller to passes the proper data for that request.

Answer (score 0):

C# does allow setting defaults other than constants, so you can't use fields / other parameters. For `url` it is okay, since that is a constant value. The concatenated string for `postData` isn't allowed.

An option would be to set the default to `null`, and check for it in your method. That *is* allowed:

```
public string MakePostRequest(string url = "www.website.com/usercp.php", string postData = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData))
    {
        postData = "username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&remember=yes&submit=Login&action=do_login&url=" + ForumUrl + "member.php?action=login";
    }
```